# Which of the following is grammaticaly correct?

Tags: grammar, word-order

There are many sentences that confuse me and they are like these two:

1. Whatever may be the reason, they failed badly.
2. Whatever the reason may be, they failed badly.

Which one is grammatically correct ?

Comment: The second one is normal. The first one is unusual, but it does sound grammatical to me, and I am trying to work out why.

Comment: I think the reason why both are possible, is that _whatever_ can be the subject of the copula "may be". In 2, _the reason_ is that subject; in 1, _Whatever_ is the subject.

Comment: It's a little old-fashioned and formal, that's all. Whatever may be the reason, whether it was that Hitler thought he might get away with what he had got without fighting for it, or whether it was that after all the preparations were not sufficiently complete--however, one thing is certain: he missed the bus. Neville Chamberlain, British Prime Minister. Whatever may be the reason, we all do warmly respect humility — in other people.“ - G. K. Chesterton.

Comment: You would typically say: Whatever the reason, they failed badly.